# WFA Window in front

Tags: c#, wpf, event-handling, topmost

I got a WFA with a TreeView in it and I added a `MouseDoubleClick` event to a treeviewItem. In code the eventhandler opens a new window.

When I try this and `doubleClick` the TreeViewItem it opens the window but it dosn't stay in front (It moves behind my page where the TreeView is)

I tryed adding a `Topmost = true` in the eventhandler but that doesn't work.

Anyone got a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with `Owner property` in order to set focus

```
var newWindow = new NewWindow();
newWindow.Owner = this;
newWindow.ShowDialog();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the owner of the child window to Main Window -

```
Window childWindow = new Window();
childWindow.Owner = mainWindow;
```

In case that doesn't solve it, post some of your code which we can look into.

Comment: childWindow.Owner = mainWindow; dosn't work.
Error: Mainwindow is a type but is used like a variable.

Comment: By `mainWindow`, i meant the instance of your MainWindow.

Comment: yeah, found it. newWindow.Owner = this;